# Javascript > operator not working in Extension

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-chrome-extension, operators

I'm simply trying to use this If statement within a loop, but for some reason that I can't figure out it isn't working

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    probeAmount: '1'
}, function(items) {
    probeavailable = document.getElementById("probeValue").innerHTML;
    console.log(probeavailable);
    console.log(items.probeAmount);
    if(probeavailable > items.probeAmount) {
        //code
    }
    else {
        //something else
    }
});
```

`console.log(probeavailable)` logs the number `14` and `console.log(items.probeAmount)` logs the number `3`, yet the If statement forwards to the else part every time.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Comment: "14" > "3" returns false. Cast it to an int.

Comment: Are you sure they are the data type you think they are? Try `typeof probeavailable` and `typeof items.probeAmount`.

Comment: Something to mention. `chrome.storage` API, unlike HTML `localStorage`, does JSON conversion on the fly. As such, for a numeric value, it makes more sense to store it as a number, i.e. `{probeAmount: 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that they aren't `14` and `3` (numbers), they're `"14"` and `"3"` (strings; that's certainly true of `probeavailable`, but I don't know about the other one). `14 > 3` is true but `"14" > "3"` (string comparison) is false. Try putting a `+` in front of each of them to force them to be numbers:

```
if(+probeavailable > +items.probeAmount) {
```

...or if either of them is user input, use `parseInt` with the appropriate radix:

```
if(parseInt(probeavailable, 10) > parseInt(items.probeAmount, 10)) {
```

Comment: Perfect. Forcing them to be a number is exactly what I needed. What I dont get is why it wouldn't work, as previously this worked just fine. A bit dumb of me not to check if they are strings. Thanks

Comment: @RicoClark: in some cases they compare correctly, but not all cases happen to work, as you've found out. That may have been why it appeared to "work" initially.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(parseInt(probeavailable) > parseInt(items.probeAmount)) {
```

instead